# Segment Fault when initialization multiple nodes

Tags: c, initialization, malloc, binary-search-tree

I am working on a binary search tree in C.  I am having a problem with initializing multiple nodes.

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node{
    int* data;
    Node* leftChild;
    Node* rightChild;
    Node* parent;
};

void initNode(Node* node, int* data){
    node->data = data;
    node->leftChild = NULL;
    node->rightChild = NULL;
    node->parent = NULL;
}
```

The above code seems to work fine when calling initNode() only once. But if I attempt to make the second call I get a segment fault.

My main looks like this:

```
int main(){
    Node* node;
    Node* node2;
    int a = 12;
    int b = 15;

    initNode(node, &a);

    printf("%i \n", *node->data);

}
```

This works. However if I do this:

```
int main(){
    Node* node;
    Node* node2;
    int a = 12;
    int b = 15;

    initNode(node, &a);
    initNode(node2, &b);

    printf("%i \n", *node->data);

}
```

I get a segment fault. Any ideas why this behavior is happening?

Comment: You need to malloc your Node

Comment: I had malloc in the function call, but this does not seem to work.  It does work if I have in main however.  Any ideas why this is?

Comment: You allocated memory to `node` as pointed by @Orel  ?

Comment: @TavishWille We can't really say unless you show the code. But a common problem is that the malloced data is not correctly returned to the caller (e.g. by assigning the malloc result to the `node` parameter which is wrong as that is scoped only to the function and will not make it back to the caller).

Comment: Interesting that you tagged `malloc`, but you never use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated memory for both node or node2. Since both the pointers are allocated on stack they will have junk values. Its just accident that the first program passes at all.

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
void initNode(Node* node, int* data){
    node->data = data;
    node->leftChild = NULL;
    node->rightChild = NULL;
    node->parent = NULL;
}
```

expects `node` to have already been initialized.

You don't do that in either of your programs. Dereferencing a pointer that hasn't been assigned is undefined behavior. It's just by chance that it worked in your first program. Who knows what memory you're overwriting.

You need to initialize `node` and `node2`.

```
Node* node = malloc(sizeof*node);
Node* node2 = malloc(sizeof*node2);
```

Just remember to `free` them once you're finished with them.

---

A much cleaner solution is to allocate the `Node`s on the stack, so you don't have to worry about calling `free`.

```
int main(void) { /* use a valid signature for main() */
    Node node; /* just a straight up Node (not a pointer) */
    Node node2;
    int a = 12;
    int b = 15;

    initNode(&node, &a); /* use address of operator on nodes */
    initNode(&node2, &b);

    printf("%i \n", *node->data);
}
```